# Possibility to get the shop name with google maps geocoder api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am wondering if it is possible to get a name for a shop, mall or restaurant by using the google geocoding api. For example I need to have '*Starbucks*' as a result if the user searched for. Using the Address Component Types from the [official api reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) doesn't seem to be able to receive this. Is there any other way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

No, the geocoder returns coordinates for postal addresses (and some "well-known" locations).  I believe you are looking for the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/), also available as a [library in the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: I am using already google.maps.places.Autocomplete() for the user input (which is working fine). In the api reference I see just to limit the autocomplete types but not to get the establishment name of the result.