# How to Retrieve Name of a Store Using Either Coordinates or Address

Tags: android, google-maps, location, coordinates, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to retrieve store names by using either coordinates or addresses and mark the store location on the map.  I can retrieve the addresses/coordinates fine, it's a matter of translating those into a store name.

If this is not supported than my possible solution would be to create a HashMap filled with coordinates and the corresponding store name

I have not seen any guides/code on this so I would greatly appreciate your help

Thank you!

Comment: did you try using the Geocoder API?

Comment: I just looked at the Geocoder API cause I didn't see it beforehand...I need to get the store name from the address/coord but Geocoder doesn't support it.....For Example: I have Bethel, CT 06801
83 Stony Hill Road and from that address it will say Big Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes u can create HashMap and store the co-ordinates.

```
 private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){ 
 int places=array.length();
 List<HashMap<String, String>> storesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> place = null;      
 for(int i=0; i<places;i++){
 try {
 get lat and long add it to hashmap
 place.put("lat", latitude);
 place.put("lng", longitude);
 storesList.add(place);

 } 
 catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}
return storesList;
}
```

then you can Iterate the values.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
     add Markers
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help if I'm going to use the HashMap but I might have found the answer on another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809685/possibilty-to-get-the-shop-name-with-google-maps-geocoder-api

Comment: Yes you can use place api..anyways u can use the same logic once u have the json :)